# How to run multiple mpi programs with srun in SLURM

Tags: mpi, hpc, slurm

I'm trying to run this command with multiple instances of a program, like this:

```
mpirun -oversubscribe -tag-output -np 1 /home/rd636/Posdoc_Posner/BioNetFit2_pull1/bin/BioNetFit2 -a load -c /home/rd636/Posdoc_Posner/BioNetFit2_pull1/parabolaA_1681692777.sconf : -oversubscribe -tag-output -np 24 /home/rd636/Posdoc_Posner/BioNetFit2_pull1/bin/BioNetFit2 -t particle -p 0 -a run -c /home/rd636/Posdoc_Posner/BioNetFit2_pull1/parabolaA_1681692777.sconf
```

In one node this mpirun command works, but when I request more than one node in my sbatch scriipt, the messages that the 24 slave processes (from the other node) receive are empty.
I asked to the HPC manager about this, and he said that I should use "srun" to run my jobs.
But how do I convert that mpirun command into an srun command?

Here is my job submission script:

```
#SBATCH --job-name=parabola2_cluster_2x10                                   # the name of your job
#SBATCH --output=/home/rd636/Posdoc_Posner/BioNetFit2_pull1/parabola_log.txt        # this is the file your output and errors go to
#SBATCH --time=1:30:00                                  # 1 hour and 30 min
#SBATCH --workdir=/home/rd636/Posdoc_Posner/BioNetFit2_pull1/bin            # your work directory
#SBATCH --mem=2000                                                  # 2GB of memory
abbreviated by -N
#SBATCH --ntasks=25                                 # number of MPI tasts (total number of cores), or (Swarm_Size*nModels)+1
module purge
module load gcc/5.4.0
module load openmpi/1.10.2
module load glibc/2.23
module load boost/1.65.0-gcc-5.4.0

time mpirun -oversubscribe -tag-output -np 1 /home/rd636/Posdoc_Posner/BioNetFit2_pull1/bin/BioNetFit2 -a load -c /home/rd636/Posdoc_Posner/BioNetFit2_pull1/parabolaA_1681692777.sconf : -oversubscribe -tag-output -np 24 /home/rd636/Posdoc_Posner/BioNetFit2_pull1/bin/BioNetFit2 -t particle -p 0 -a run -c /home/rd636/Posdoc_Posner/BioNetFit2_pull1/parabolaA_1681692777.sconf
echo "Synchronous GA, 24 subparticles, 12 particles, 2 models, 100 generations"
```

I can't use the multiprogram file approach because my command is too long, and changing to relative paths is not an option, unfortunately.

Comment: since you `mpirun -np 1`, i assume your app `MPI_Comm_spawn()`. as far as i am concerned, Open MPI is not able to `MPI_Comm_spawn()` with direct run (e.g. `srun` in your case). the `echo` message suggests you are running 1+24=25 tasks, and this is what you asked SLURM, so why do you need the `-oversubscribe` option ?

Comment: -oversubscribe doesn't seem to matter, so I just removed it then. The app doesn't use MPI_Comm_spawn(), and it is not running with only -np 1, the command is running two instances of the program, one with -np 1 and the other with -np 24.

Comment: My bad, i did not read the full `mpirun` command line. As long as OpenMPI was configure'd with `--with-pmi` you can basically replace `mpirun a.out` with `srun a.out`. I do not think `srun` supports multiple binaries, so you have to write a simple wrapper and check `$SLURM_PROCID`